# Hide div's 5 to 7 if less then 8 div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Bear with me on this. I have a loop in Wordpress that shows 8 posts per page. But sometimes the loop doesn't have 8 posts. If that happens I would like to `hide` div 5 to 7. And if there are 8 posts per page (8 div's) that show all 8 posts.

So let's say I have the following HTML

```
<div class="post">Post 1</div>
<div class="post">Post 2</div>
<div class="post">Post 3</div>
<div class="post">Post 4</div>
<div class="post">Post 5</div>
<div class="post">Post 6</div>
<div class="post">Post 7</div>
```

Than It will only show post 1 to 4 and NOT post 5 to 7. But if I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="post">Post 1</div>
<div class="post">Post 2</div>
<div class="post">Post 3</div>
<div class="post">Post 4</div>
<div class="post">Post 5</div>
<div class="post">Post 6</div>
<div class="post">Post 7</div>
<div class="post">Post 8</div>
```

It will show all posts...

I have been experimenting with `lenght` but I'm quite new to jQuery. I've got this: `console.log( $('.post').length);`. This shows `6` so I figure that I need to do something with

`if .post < 8 != < 4 addClass 'hide'`

So I can hide them?? Or something like that?

Comment: Just a side question: would modifying the loop in wordpress (I guess some php) not an option? If you do this on the server you would prevent eventual screen flashes and save client-side processing time. If you however need to have all divs in the DOM (for eventual later use) - yes this can't be used.

Comment: Great suggestion but I do need the divs for later use :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check length and `hide` posts that are `:gt(3)` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2140/)

```
if($('.post').length < 8) $('.post:gt(3)').hide()
```

Comment: It's :gt(3) actually :) since it works over indexing and not count

Answer (score 2):

I would use some kind of flag to mark the two different states and than use CSS for hiding. Example:

```js
function check($container) {
  if($container.find('> .post').length < 8) {
    $container.addClass('reduced');
  }
}
check(jQuery('#test1'));
check(jQuery('#test2'));
```

```css
#test1 {
  background: blue;
}
#test2 {
  background: red;
}

.reduced .post:nth-child(1n+5){
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>demo</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test1">
  <div class="post">1</div>
  <div class="post">2</div>
  <div class="post">3</div>
  <div class="post">4</div>
  <div class="post">5</div>
  <div class="post">6</div>
  <div class="post">7</div>
  <div class="post">8</div>
</div>
<div id="test2">
  <div class="post">1</div>
  <div class="post">2</div>
  <div class="post">3</div>
  <div class="post">4</div>
  <div class="post">5</div>
  <div class="post">6</div>
  <div class="post">7</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

See https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3 for browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length of the collection and then do the desired action.

In this case, we are using the [jQuery.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter the posts and select only those that have an index, greater than 3. The filter uses the [:gt selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

```
var $post = jQuery(".post");
if($post.length < 8){
    $post.filter("gt:(3)").hide();
}
```

In case you wonder, the number is 3, because it is an index, which starts at zero (0). Then we are counting one by one and the 4th element is with index 3. So, the filter will select all elements with an index, greater than 3 (all elements which are not the first 4 elements) - in other words, the 5th element and all the others after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply just with CSS.

```
.post:nth-child(n+4):not(:nth-last-child(n+5)) ~ .post {
  display: none;
}
```

It hides all posts after the fourth if the fourth isn't also fifth from the end (which means there's 8 elements total). It's simple, clean, and doesn't require any imperative shenanigans.

*Solution inspired by [this post](http://andr3.net/blog/post/142).*

Answer (score 0):

Use each() method, within it write if statement for index > then you need

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var length =$('.post').length;
        if(length < 8 && length > 4 ){
           $('.post').each(function(i,elem){
            if(i>=4){
              $(elem).hide();
              }
           })
      }
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and thanks for your answer. A little explanation will improve the quality and acceptability of your answer.